# Why pl sql assignment operator throws error while reading from sql query?

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
set serveroutput on;
 declare

      v_emp_first_name  US_EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME%TYPE;

      BEGIN

       select us_employees.first_name into v_emp_first_name  from us_employees where email = 'jbutt@gmail.com';

       dbms_output.put_line('v_emp_first_name  --> ' || v_emp_first_name);

       v_emp_first_name := select first_name from us_employees where email = 'kris@gmail.com';

       dbms_output.put_line('v_emp_first_name  --> ' || v_emp_first_name);

      END;
```

When I compile above code the below statement throws error

```
    v_emp_first_name := select first_name from us_employees where email = 'kris@gmail.com';
```

Is it not possible to read a column value via a sql query and map that value using  assignment operator ?

If i have the below code alone then it compile and works fine

```
    select us_employees.first_name into v_emp_first_name  from us_employees where email = 'jbutt@gmail.com';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is NO. You can't assign the output of a scalar query to a variable. The proper syntax for your "assignment" is the one you are already aware of.

I am sure that you will then ask WHY. Why did Oracle choose that "weird" syntax for assignment, and not the simpler one you tried?

The answer is that in more general cases a `select` statement may return multiple columns, not just one; and the values from multiple columns can be "assigned" to multiple variables (local to the PL/SQL block) simultaneously. Which, by the way, is the more common usage - people extract one "record" at a time, rather than a single value. So, how would you re-write the "select **into**" operation as an "assignment" (or multiple "assignments")? There is no natural way to do that.

You may ask why Oracle doesn't allow "your" assignment syntax, in the case of a single column selected, *in addition to* the `select into` syntax (which is needed for multi-column rows anyway). The answer is that would be wasteful. We already have a syntax - that we need for more general cases anyway; we don't need one more.

You might say that we could put all the receiving local variables into a record type, and do a single assignment (to a record) even for general "rows" returned by a `select`. Alas, SQL statements return rows, not records; rows are a SQL concept, and specifically they are not a data type. Perhaps Oracle could do further development along those lines (to add functionality that doesn't exist today), but why bother - they already have a perfectly fine syntax for what you need, and you already know what that syntax is - without needing to define a record type to hold all your local variables, then define a "record type" for rows coming from a SQL `select` statement, then .....

Comment: Thanks for the answer Why did Oracle choose that "weird" syntax for assignment, and not the simpler one I  tried?

Answer (score 1):

You have issue with this code:

```
v_emp_first_name := select first_name from us_employees where email = 'kris@gmail.com';
```

You can not use the assignment operator against the query as you have used.

Replace this assignment `:=` with `INTO` as follows:

```
select first_name INTO v_emp_first_name from us_employees where email = 'kris@gmail.com';
```

Comment: Into what? This won’t work as written. The OP already has the correct statement, he is just asking why the wrong one is wrong.

Comment: @mathguy I just gave answer to use the `INTO` instead of `:=`. I think this is needed in oracle. But anyway, You gave the nice answer.

Comment: Use into, of course. But your code example is missing the variable name after INTO. That is why I asked, into WHAT?

Comment: If you look closely at the OP’s post, you will see that he already had the correct select ... into ... statement, and he knew that worked. That really wasn’t his question - he only wanted to know why the direct assignment doesn’t work.